# Grid view without using FlatList in React native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, gridview

I have just started to learn react native. I want to create grid view. I know I can do it with using `FlatList`. But I don't want that. I just map the data from the array and make a grid using this. But it didn't worked. Here is my code.

```
const ingredientnsViews = INGREDIENTS.map(data => {
  return (
     <View style={styles.gridIngredients}>
       <Image
         style={styles.ingredientImage}
         resizeMode="contain"
         source={data.image}
       />
       <Text style={styles.ingredientsText}>{data.title}</Text>
     </View>
  );
});
```

This is my style.

```
ingredientsText: {
fontFamily: AppFonts.Primary.Sans.Regular,
fontStyle: 'normal',
fontWeight: '400',
alignSelf: 'center',
fontSize: 12,
color: COLORS.black,
},

gridIngredients: {
marginTop: 12,
width: '30%',
flexDirection: 'row',
justifyContent: 'center',
backgroundColor: COLORS.tabBgColor,
paddingStart: 16,
paddingEnd: 16,
paddingTop: 8,
paddingBottom: 8,
borderRadius: 8,
},

ingredientImage: {
width: 15,
alignSelf: 'center',
height: 15,
},
```

`INGREDIENTS` is my kind of array. I need grid with `4` comumns.
Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to `ScrollView`. Inside `ScrollView` you can render your grid view with map.

https://snack.expo.dev/O9KI-80gn

please check below add code.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {Text, Image, View, ScrollView, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';


// or any pure javascript modules available in npm
import {Card} from 'react-native-paper';
const INGREDIENTS = [
  {name: 'Banana', image: 'https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300'},
  {name: 'Apple', image: 'https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300'},
  {name: 'Orange', image: 'https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300'},
  {name: 'Banana', image: 'https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300'},
  {name: 'Apple', image: 'https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300'},

  {name: 'Orange', image: 'https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300'},
    {name: 'Banana', image: 'https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300'},
  {name: 'Apple', image: 'https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300'},
  {name: 'Orange', image: 'https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300'},
  {name: 'Banana', image: 'https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300'},
  {name: 'Apple', image: 'https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300'},
  {name: 'Orange', image: 'https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300'},
  
];
export default function App() {
  const ingredientnsViews = data => {
    return (
      <View style={styles.gridIngredients}>
        <Image
          style={styles.ingredientImage}
          resizeMode="contain"
          source={data.image}
        />
        <Text style={styles.ingredientsText}>{data.name}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  };
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <ScrollView>
        <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', flexWrap: 'wrap'}}>
          {INGREDIENTS.map((value, index) => {
            return ingredientnsViews(value);
          })}
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
  ingredientsText: {
    //fontFamily: AppFonts.Primary.Sans.Regular,
    fontStyle: 'normal',
    fontWeight: '400',
    alignSelf: 'center',
    fontSize: 12,
    color: 'black',
  },

  gridIngredients: {
    marginTop: 12,
    width: '22%',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'yellow',
    paddingStart: 16,
    paddingEnd: 16,
    paddingTop: 8,
    marginRight: 10,
    paddingBottom: 8,
    borderRadius: 8,
  },

  ingredientImage: {
    width: 15,
    alignSelf: 'center',
    height: 15,
  },
});
```

OutPut:-

[image]

Comment: Okay. But i have a already parent _ScrollView_

Comment: can you please add complete code snippet ? according to shared question we look your only don't want to flatlist to create grid

Comment: if we already have `ScrollView` as a parent you only need to add `map` inside `ScrollView`. and return a `View`

Comment: Can you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68661809/validation-not-working-properly-in-carousel-view-pager-on-particular-page

Comment: The grid is not centered. As you can see, there is no spacing on the left on first column. We can add marginLeft to the entire parent View, but it won't be responsive. I used "space-evenly" at the flex view, it looks good, but the last row will not be aligned properly if that row has less than 4 items. Any idea how to fix this?